# Singleton instance of controller per user for Ajax request in Grails?

Tags: ajax, grails, heroku

I am writing a small Grails application for a small number of users (max 10). It would be hosted on Heroku free hosting (1 dyno=512 MB RAM).

The app would have one user form which on submit would trigger an Ajax request that spawns a thread in the controller.(The default submit action is prevented via preventDefault() because the task is time consuming and Heroku has a timeout of about 30s).

For example the thread fetches a list of items from an external api/url, the controller would have an instance variable say `itemFetched`. The webpage of user form would contain a progress widget which would periodically show the value of this `itemFetched`.

`usera` starts a thread and while it is running in the background, the user would see the status of `itemFetched` when he leaves that page and hits the url again.

How do I create a "per user" controller (as long as the thread spawned via Ajax thread is running), rather than per HTTP request (i.e. prototype scope)?

Comment: Have you considered using a session scoped service? This would allow an instance of a service per http session. Pretty much what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I think a session scoped service would not work if the user leaves the page and again comes back because it would start a new "session".

Comment: Nope, that's exactly what the session is for - to maintain state between requests.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith ahh yeah, got it. Such a big idiot of me to have forgotten that simple point!!

Comment: @JoshuaMoore you can put that as the answer. I am sure that would work. I would accept with upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular situation a session scoped service would be a perfect fit. You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/services.html#scopedServices).

By making your service session scoped, each HTTP session will have it's own instance of the service and you can maintain state between requests within a given session.

Comment: Can we use session scoped service directly by injecting into a controller? Or do we need to use Session proxies? I face the issue as I outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411774/grails-unable-to-inject-session-scoped-service-to-controller