# Grails unable to inject session scoped service to controller

Tags: grails, service

I am trying to inject a session scoped service to controller. Here is my controller class ActionController.groovy:

```
    package rafonline

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
class ActionController {
    def tweetingService
    def index() {
    }


    def retweetUsers(){
        String message="done"
        boolean success=true
        try {
            final def handles=String.valueOf(params.handles).trim().split("\n")
            final def passwords=String.valueOf(params.passwords).trim().split("\n")
            final def numRTs=String.valueOf(params.numRTs).trim().split("\n")
            final def statusIdsString=String.valueOf(params.tweetURLs).trim().split("\n")
            if(!tweetingService.isRunning){
                new Thread(new Runnable(){

                    @Override
                    void run() {
                        tweetingService.retweetUsers(statusIdsString,handles,passwords,numRTs);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message=e.getMessage()
            success=false
        }
        render contentType: 'text/json', text: [success: success, message: "${message}"] as JSON
    }
    def getUpdateProgress(){
       render contentType: 'text/json',text:[running:tweetingService.isRunning,message: tweetingService.messsage] as JSON
    }

}
```

Here is my session scoped service TweetingService.groovy:
package rafonline

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.jsoup.Connection
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element
import org.jsoup.select.Elements

@Transactional
class TweetingService {
    private final String PARAM1 = "some1";
    private final String PARAM2 = "some2";
    private final String PARAM3 = "some3";
    private final String USER_AGENT = "some4";
    private final Long TIMEOUT = 60000
    static scope = "session"
    def messsage = "Waiting"
    def isRunning = false
    def stopit=false
    def retweetUsers(String[] statusIds, String[] username, String[] password, String[] numRTs) {
        if (isRunning) {
            return
        } else {
            try {
                int count = 1;
                isRunning = true
                statusIds=convertStatusURLArrayToStatusIDArray(statusIds)
                def totalLength = statusIds.length

                for (int i = 0; i < statusIds.length; i++) {
                    def statusId = statusIds[i]
                    def numRT = username.length
                    try{
                        numRT=Integer.parseInt(numRTs[i])
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        numRT=username.length
                    }
                    shuffleArray(username, password)
                    messsage = "Processing ${i + 1} of ${totalLength}"
                    for (int j = 0; j < numRT; j++) {
                        if(stop){
                            stop=false
                            break;
                        }

                        try {
                            //Do something

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        messsage = "Total Processed: ${totalLength}    Failed: ${totalLength - count}   Success:${count}"
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                isRunning=false
            }
        }
    }

    def Map<String, String> getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        // Google form id
        Element loginform = doc.getElementsByTag("form").get(2);
        Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
        List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");

            if (key.equals("session[username_or_email]"))
                value = username;
            else if (key.equals("session[password]"))
                value = password;

            map.put(key, value);
        }

        // build parameters list

        return map;
    }
    def convertStatusURLArrayToStatusIDArray(String[]statusIdArray){
        String[]outputArray=new String[statusIdArray.length]
        for(int i=0;i<statusIdArray.length;i++){
            outputArray[i]=getStatusIdFromTweetURL(statusIdArray[i]);
        }
        return outputArray
    }
    def getStatusIdFromTweetURL(String tweetURL){
        def tokens=tweetURL.split("/")
        for(String s:tokens){
            try{
                Long.parseLong(s)
                return s
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
        return null
    }
    static void shuffleArray(String[] usernames, String[] passwords) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = usernames.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            String a = usernames[index];
            usernames[index] = usernames[i];
            usernames[i] = a;

            String b = passwords[index];
            passwords[index] = passwords[i];
            passwords[i] = b;
        }
    }
    def stop(){
        stopit=Boolean.TRUE
    }
}


        def retweetUsers(){
            String message="done"
            boolean success=true
            try {
                final def handles=String.valueOf(params.handles).trim().split("\n")
                final def passwords=String.valueOf(params.passwords).trim().split("\n")
                final def numRTs=String.valueOf(params.numRTs).trim().split("\n")
                final def statusIdsString=String.valueOf(params.tweetURLs).trim().split("\n")
                if(!tweetingService.isRunning){
                    new Thread(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        void run() {
                            tweetingService.retweetUsers(statusIdsString,handles,passwords,numRTs);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message=e.getMessage()
                success=false
            }
            render contentType: 'text/json', text: [success: success, message: "${message}"] as JSON
        }
        def getUpdateProgress(){
           render contentType: 'text/json',text:[running:tweetingService.isRunning,message: tweetingService.messsage] as JSON
        }

    }
```

But on running the above app, I get the following error:

```
2015-04-02 16:47:22,552 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'rafonline.ActionController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tweetingService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'rafonline.ActionController': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tweetingService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    Line | Method
->>  529 | doCreateBean                    in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    127 | doCreateBean                    in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|    458 | createBean . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
|    296 | getObject                       in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1
|    223 | getSingleton . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry
|    293 | doGetBean                       in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory
|    194 | getBean . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    628 | preInstantiateSingletons        in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
|    932 | finishBeanFactoryInitialization in org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext
|    479 | refresh                         in     ''
|    156 | getApplicationContext . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration
|    169 | configure                       in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator
|    127 | configure . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    122 | configureWebApplicationContext  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils
|    108 | initWebApplicationContext . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader
|    112 | contextInitialized              in org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
|   4973 | listenerStart . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
|   5467 | startInternal                   in     ''
|    150 | start . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase
|   1559 | call                            in org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild
|   1549 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    262 | run                             in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                             in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tweetingService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

So am I not allowed simply inject a session scoped service to a controller? Or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have already seen [this](http://ldaley.com/post/436635056/scoped-services-proxies-in-grails) link and tried setting static proxy=true. Yet it does not work and same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think error suggests you a solution

```
'tweetingService': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton;
```

define

`static proxy=true` in service it should work

for further [ref](http://ldaley.com/post/436635056/scoped-services-proxies-in-grails)

Comment: I have already tried this. I have seen the link first before posting this question

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the default scope for controllers in Config.groovy

```
// The default scope for controllers. May be prototype, session or singleton.
// If unspecified, controllers are prototype scoped.
grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'session'
```